# Multiply xarray map by country specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-xarray

I have one `xarray` dataset (`da_main`) with `lat`, `lon` dimensions and I want to multiply this dataset by another dataset that depend on the country (`da_value_per_country`).

I also have a dataset giving me for each location (same dimension and coordinates as `da_main`) country name (`da_country`).

I was thinking of combining `da_main` and `da_country` with:

```
    ds = xr.combine_by_coords(
        [da_main, da_country],
    )
ds = ds.set_coords("Countries") #Countries is the name of the da_country dimension
```

The problem is that it does not create a new dimension.

I found an inefficient work around turning the `xarray` into pd `DataFrame`, it is slow with heavy data.

I was thinking of combining `da_main` and `da_country` with:

```
ds = xr.combine_by_coords(
[da_main, da_new],
)
ds = ds.set_coords("Countries")
#Countries is the name of the da_country dimension
```

The problem is that it does not create a new dimension.

I found an inefficient work around turning the `xarray` into `pd DataFrame`, it is slow with heavy data.

```
    df = ds.to_dataframe().reset_index()
    df = df.dropna()
    new_index = list(da_main.coords) + [new_dim]
```

I am new to `xarray`, and I'm sure there is an way to do that (without converting to `dataframe` and going back to `xarray` after that).

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [mre]. Please do not post links to code and reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nicer and much more efficient way using comprehension list over the list of countries:

```
da_coutry_with_dim = xr.concat(
    [da_country.Countries == country for country in list_countries],
    dim="Countries",
)
da_coutry_with_dim = da_coutry_with_dim.assign_coords(
    coords={"Countries": list_countries}
)
```